# Case of different directory for translation with angular-translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, translation, angular-translate

I have some issues with angular-translate especially with the loading of translation.
I am programming a website in angular for my school project. In this project, we have an association with differents sports sections.

Each section have specifics translations due to sport's language, and a default translation to avoid issues in case of unavailable key.

### Your environment

- version of angular-translate 2.11.0
- version of angular  1.3.20

---

```
translationDir
  |
  |
  |-----default
             | ---i18n_en.json
             | ---i18n_fr.json
  |
  |-----specificSport
              | module1
                     | ---i18n_en.json
                     | ---i18n_fr.json
              | module2
                     | ---i18n_en.json
                     | ---i18n_fr.json
```

angular.module.config here

```
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.useCookieStorage();

$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
            urlTemplate: '{part}-i18n_{lang}.json',
            loadFailureHandler: 'translationHandler'
 })
```

And the factory

```
factory('translationHandler', function ($q, $log) {
      return function (part, lang, response) {
        $log.error('The "' + part + '/' + lang + '" part was not loaded.');
        return $q.when({});
      };
    })
```

Actually, if the key is unavailable in section, we load English key of this section.

But this is possible to have unavailable key in English too, due to specific translation (we could include default translation everywhere, but it's bad and ugly).

Have you an idea to fix this please ?